# if else statement with mulitple variables

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

i need an if else statement in sqlite3 query, but i can't find the error.

if the name is available it should update the variable disabled. if the name does not exist, insert it

```
name = 'testname'
disabled = 'x'
finish = '1'
runtime = '1'
c.execute("IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM infos WHERE name=?', (name,)) THEN UPDATE infos SET disabled=? WHERE name=?', (disabled,name) ELSE INSERT INTO infos VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (None, name, disabled, finish, runtime))


error:
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "IF": syntax error
```

I've tried this command too, but I suspect the python command is wrong:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO infos VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT(?) DO UPDATE SET disabled = (?);", (None, name, disabled, finish, runtime),(name),(disabled))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.24.0+ and you have defined the column `name` as `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) you can use [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html), like this:

```
name = 'testname'
disabled = 'x'
finish = '1'
runtime = '1'

sql = """
INSERT INTO infos(name, disabled, finish, runtime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE
SET disabled = excluded.disabled, finish = excluded.finish, runtime = excluded.runtime"""

c.execute(sql, (name, disabled, finish, runtime))
```

See how it works in SQLite in this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cde0365d70360e37d6987089d437f4bb).